# Delphi 7 32 bits execute and wait 64 bits process

Tags: delphi, process

I used to use the function below to start and wait unil the end of a process.

It works fine for starting and waiting for 32 bits process on a 32 bits or 64 bits OS.

But on a 64 bits OS, it returns immediately when i launch a 64 bits process (WaitForSingleObject = WAIT_OBJECT_0).

For example, if my app (32 bits), launch mstsc.exe on a 32 bits OS it is ok but it don't wait on a 64 bits OS certainly because mstsc.exe is a 64 bits program.

Any solution ?

```
function gShellExecuteAndWait(
                              vHandle     : HWND;
                              vOperation  : string;
                              vFichier    : string;
                              vParametres : string;
                              vRepertoire : string;
                              vAffichage  : Integer;
                              vDuree      : DWORD;
                              var vErreur : string
                             ) : Boolean;
var
  vSEInfo  : TShellExecuteInfo;
  vAttente : DWORD;
begin
  // Initialisation
  Result   := True;
  vErreur  := '';
  vAttente := 0;

  // Initialisation de la structure ShellExecuteInfo
  ZeroMemory(@vSEInfo, SizeOf(vSEInfo));

  // Remplissage de la structure ShellExecuteInfo
  vSEInfo.cbSize       := SizeOf(vSEInfo);
  vSEInfo.fMask        := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  vSEInfo.Wnd          := vHandle;
  vSEInfo.lpVerb       := PAnsiChar(vOperation);
  vSEInfo.lpFile       := PAnsiChar(vFichier);
  vSEInfo.lpParameters := PAnsiChar(vParametres);
  vSEInfo.lpDirectory  := PAnsiChar(vRepertoire);
  vSEInfo.nShow        := vAffichage;

  // L'exécution a réussi
  if ShellExecuteEx(@vSEInfo) then
  begin
    // Attendre la fin du process ou une erreur
    while True do
    begin

      case WaitForSingleObject(vSEInfo.hProcess, 250) of

        WAIT_ABANDONED :
        begin
          Result  := False;
          vErreur := 'L''attente a été annulée.';
          Break;
        end;

        WAIT_OBJECT_0 :
        begin
          Break;
        end;

        WAIT_TIMEOUT :
        begin
          // Initialisation
          vAttente := vAttente + 250;

          // Le délai d'attente n'a pas été atteint
          if vAttente < vDuree then
          begin
            Application.ProcessMessages();
          end

          // Le délai d'attente est dépassé
          else
          begin
            Result  := False;
            vErreur := 'Le délai d''attente a été dépassé.';
            Break;
          end;
        end;

        WAIT_FAILED :
        begin
          Result := False;
          vErreur := SysErrorMessage(GetLastError());
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end

  // L'exécution a échoué
  else
  begin
    Result  := False;
    vErreur := SysErrorMessage(GetLastError());
  end;
end;
```

Comment: An aside. Here you are starting a new process where you know the executable. CreateProcess is the API for that. ShellExecuteEx is when you need to shell to work out how to do it. Since you know the name of the executable it makes more sense, in my view, to call CreateProcess directly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is that the following happens:

1. You have a 32 bit process running in the WOW64 emulator under 64 bit Windows.
2. You attempt to start a new process named `mstsc.exe`.
3. The system searches on the path for that and finds it in the system directory.
4. Because you run under WOW64, the system directory is the 32 bit system directory, SysWOW64.
5. The process starts and immediately detects that it is a 32 bit process running under WOW64 under a 64 bit system.
6. The 32 bit `mstsc.exe` then determines that it needs to start the 64 bit version of `mstsc.exe`, which it does, passing on any command line arguments, and then immediately terminates.

This would explain why your new process immediately terminates.

Some possible solutions:

1. Disable file system redirection before you start the new process. Obviously you should re-enable it immediately afterwards.
2. Create a small 64 bit program that lives in the same directory as your executable, whose sole job is to launch programs. You can start this process and ask it to launch the other process. That would allow you to escape from the clutches of the emulator and its redirection.

Comment: A third option might be to use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx) to enumerate the running processes if your spawned process terminates quickly, checking if any process was spawned by the terminated process, and if so then call `OpenProcess()` on its reported processID and wait on it as needed.

Comment: +1 fwiw, I can confirm the 32 bit mstsc starting the 64 bit mstsc but I do wonder *why* it determines it needs to start the 64 bit version? This doesn't happen for a *simple* application like notepad.

Comment: @Lieven This is terminal services client is it not? Presumably that is sufficiently complex that it won't work in the emulator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - There seem to be a lot of [related questions](https://www.google.be/search?hl=nl&q=mstsc+32+64+bit&sourceid=ie8&rls=com.microsoft:nl-be:IE-Address&ie=&oe=) but I have yet to find the actual reason for this. I assume you are right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right. If I rename mstsc.exe in SysWOW64 I have "File not found". So mstsc.exe is launched in SysWOW64 and then re-launch the 64 bits version in System32. I will try to disable system redirection as you mentioned and give a return. It seems that this is special to mstsc.exe because the same situation does not occur with notepad.exe.

Comment: Yes, definitely special to this process. I personally would make a small 64 bit launcher. That's the cleanest way to escape from the emulator in my view.

Comment: @RemyLebeau As I mentionned above the situation is not the same with mstsc.exe and notepad.exe which are presents in 32 bits and 64 bits version. Your proposal would be a general solution. Thank you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tested with file system redirection disabled and it works like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

In the case of launching mstsc.exe from a 32 bits program on a 64 OS, I modified the function like this (it is a first try not the definitive version) ans it works like a charm !

Thank you @DavidHeffernan !

But be aware that if you don't know what process will be lauched (and its behavio) you need to consider @RemyLebeau global solution.

Thanks you !

```
function gShellExecuteAndWait(
                              vHandle     : HWND;
                              vOperation  : string;
                              vFichier    : string;
                              vParametres : string;
                              vRepertoire : string;
                              vAffichage  : Integer;
                              vDuree      : DWORD;
                              var vErreur : string
                             ) : Boolean;
var
  vSEInfo  : TShellExecuteInfo;
  vAttente : DWORD;

  IsWow64Process                 :function(aProcess: THandle; var aWow64Process: Bool): Bool; stdcall;
  Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection :function(aOldValue :pointer) :Bool; stdcall;
  Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection  :function(aOldValue :pointer) :Bool; stdcall;


  Wow64 :Bool;
  OldFs :pointer;
begin
  // Initialisation
  Result   := True;
  vErreur  := '';
  vAttente := 0;
  OldFS    := nil;

  IsWow64Process := Windows.GetProcAddress(Windows.GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'), 'IsWow64Process');

  if Assigned(IsWow64Process) then
  begin
    IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess, Wow64);
  end
  else
  begin
    Wow64 := False;
  end;

  if Wow64 then
  begin
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection := GetProcAddress(Windows.GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'), 'Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection');

    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(OldFS);
  end;


  // Initialisation de la structure ShellExecuteInfo
  ZeroMemory(@vSEInfo, SizeOf(vSEInfo));

  // Remplissage de la structure ShellExecuteInfo
  vSEInfo.cbSize       := SizeOf(vSEInfo);
  vSEInfo.fMask        := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  vSEInfo.Wnd          := vHandle;
  vSEInfo.lpVerb       := PAnsiChar(vOperation);
  vSEInfo.lpFile       := PAnsiChar(vFichier);
  vSEInfo.lpParameters := PAnsiChar(vParametres);
  vSEInfo.lpDirectory  := PAnsiChar(vRepertoire);
  vSEInfo.nShow        := vAffichage;

  // L'exécution a réussi
  if ShellExecuteEx(@vSEInfo) then
  begin
    // Attendre la fin du process ou une erreur
    while True do
    begin

      case WaitForSingleObject(vSEInfo.hProcess, 250) of

        WAIT_ABANDONED :
        begin
          Result  := False;
          vErreur := 'L''attente a été annulée.';
          Break;
        end;

        WAIT_OBJECT_0 :
        begin
          Break;
        end;

        WAIT_TIMEOUT :
        begin
          // Initialisation
          vAttente := vAttente + 250;

          // Le délai d'attente n'a pas été atteint
          if vAttente < vDuree then
          begin
            Application.ProcessMessages();
          end

          // Le délai d'attente est dépassé
          else
          begin
            Result  := False;
            vErreur := 'Le délai d''attente a été dépassé.';
            Break;
          end;
        end;

        WAIT_FAILED :
        begin
          Result := False;
          vErreur := SysErrorMessage(GetLastError());
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end

  // L'exécution a échoué
  else
  begin
    Result  := False;
    vErreur := SysErrorMessage(GetLastError());
  end;

  if Wow64 then
  begin
    Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection := GetProcAddress(Windows.GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'), 'Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection');
    Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldFs);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are disabling redirection too long. I would definitely use `CreateProcess`. But all the same, even with `ShellExecuteEx` the steps are: DisableFSR, Call ShellExecuteEx, EnableFST, Wait for the process.